# Jest + Supertest | Jest detecting open handles

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to get rid of jest message "Jest has detected the following 2 open handles" when running my tests. But I've reached a dead-end as of right now.
This is one of my tests I'm attempting to fix:

```js
  describe('POST /products', function () {
  let agent, server
  beforeEach(function (done) {
    server = app.listen(3001, (err) => {
      if (err) return done(err);
      agent = supertest(server)
      done();
    })
    utils.reset()
  })
  it('Adds a new product', function () {
    utils.testCategories().push('Celulares') // This function returns an array of strings
    return agent
      .post('/products')
      .send({
        name: 'iPhone 13 Pro',
        brand: 'Apple',
        category: 'Celulares',
        stock: 8
      })
      .expect(201)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(function (res) {
        expect(res.body).toEqual({
          name: 'iPhone 13 Pro',
          categoryId: 1,
          brand: 'Apple',
          stock: 8,
          available: true,
          reviews: [],
          rating: 0
        })
        expect(utils.testProducts()).toHaveLength(1) // This one an array of objects
        expect(utils.testProducts()[0].name).toEqual('iPhone 13 Pro')
      })
      afterEach((done) => {
        server.close(done)
      })
    })
  })
```

I don't see anything wrong with that code, I open the server, then I close it.
Here is the route I'm trying to test:

```js
router.post('/products', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, brand, category, stock } = req.body;
  addProduct(name, brand, category, stock) // This function makes an async operation with a fake db
    .then((results) => {
      res.status(201).send(results)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).send({ error: err.message }))
})
```

Once the tests are done, jest prints this message on the console

```js
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  bound-anonymous-fn

       6 |   let agent, server
       7 |   beforeEach(function (done) {
    >  8 |     server = app.listen(3001, (err) => {
         |                  ^
       9 |       if (err) return done(err);
      10 |       agent = supertest(server)
      11 |       done();

      at Function.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/11.test.js:8:18)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
```

Maybe it's worth noting that in the GET requests this message do not have this issue at all.
Also, I've tried using --forceExit when executing the tests, but this is not a proper solution, and it actually keeps printing the message.
Any provided advise would be most apreciated

---

**SOLUTION:**
After updating jest to version jest@29.2.1 and ts-jest to ts-jest@29.0.3 the error has dissapeared.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this has been fixed in more recent updates, an upgrade to `jest@29.2.1` and `ts-jest@29.0.3` resolved it for me.

Comment: After a couple of months I checked on this and upgrading the packages seems to work, such a luck that it was a package issue then.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same.

I don't know what is the issue/cause - but more can be seen in github repositories of jest (and supertest maybe).

I downgraded my packages: `npm i jest@26.6.3 ts-jest@26.5.6 -D`, previously i had `"jest": "^27.5.1",` and `"ts-jest": "^27.1.4",`. With jest/ts-jest versions of `26.x.x` I am not facing warnings anymore.

I did my downgrade based on this comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11649#issuecomment-992690198

Comment: It looks like this has been fixed in more recent updates, an upgrade to `jest@29.2.1` and `ts-jest@29.0.3` resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, if you're also using `body-parser` on your express app, then there's an active bug that also creates this issue: https://github.com/ladjs/supertest/issues/772